# Why my angular interceptor always return 404 code error?

Tags: angularjs, interceptor

My code:

```
     app.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q) {
      return {

        responseError: function (response) {
         console.log("error111111"+JSON.stringify(response));
         if(response.status==403)
          console.log("403");
        else if(response.status==401)
          console.log("401");
        else
          console.log("404");
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    };
    });
    app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
    }]);
```

I'd like to handle status code response. But, it always return 404 code in responseError.

I did a simulation with PHP to return me 403 status => http_response_code(403);

In my chrome inspect shows me 403 code error, but when I see the status code of Interceptor shows me 404 . Why?

Ps: My request is being done using angular jsonp.

Any Help?

Comment: jsonp is a different type of request than XMLHttpRequest, it's a script request

Comment: You have reason. I changed from $http.jsonp to $http.get and so I received the right status. Thank you